# How Do I delete All Outbound links on my website?

Tags: wordpress, anchor

I used a product importation software that imported multiple products from a different website on to mine(dropship), however, the only problem is that several of the product descriptions contain anchor texts with outbound links to the original website. I have hundreds of products and removing them manually would take forever. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: forgot to mention this is a wordpress website

Comment: There are multiple methods... you could for instance construct a mysql query, a wpdb query and update all descriptions where a link is present. You could get a plugin that bulk updated descriptions for woocommerce (as thats what i assume you're using) - you could loop over all products with a `wp_query` and update descriptions that way and many more methods. Whats your attempt so far?

Comment: I'm not going to lie, all I've tried are a couple of plugins, but I've had no luck with them. What would you suggest to be the quickest and most effective method? And how would I go about doing it? I'm not going to lie, I'm kind of a beginner compared to most.

Comment: Do you have basic knowledge of PHP and WordPress development? Or are you looking for a solution that doesn't require coding?